# Bash - Can i repeat the same line of code for all items in a folder?

Tags: bash

I'd like to use a program to extract a layer from an XCF image and export it to a png of the same name. The problem is, i have 1000 images and copy/pasting each line into a script really defeats the purpose. I thought something like this would work, but it fails after naming the first image '*.png'.

```
xcf2png *.xcf "Pasted Layer #1" > *.png
```

I works fine if i do it line by line, like this, but this kind of defeats the purpose of a script.

```
xcf2png image1.xcf "Pasted Layer #1" > image1.png
xcf2png image2.xcf "Pasted Layer #1" > image2.png
```

Comment: Thanks Rup! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bash's built-in `for`, then e.g. `echo` and `sed` in backticks to change the extension: something like

```
for _t in *.xcf; do xcf2png $_t "Pasted Layer #1" > `echo $_t |sed -e "s/xcf$/png/"`; done
```

See `man bash` for syntax. (I've always used `_t` as the loop variable - I don't know where I got that from :-/ )

Comment: For looping over files, a common loop variable is `f`